# Swift and SecTrust

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some troubles trying to convert code that I've found in the Apple documentation into swift code. To be precise it is stuff about TSL and certificates...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html

This is the original code in Objective-C

```
SecTrustResultType secresult = kSecTrustResultInvalid;
if (SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &secresult) != errSecSuccess) 
     return;
}
```

And this is my attempt...

```
var secresult:SecTrustResultType = kSecTrustResultInvalid // ERROR 1 
if (SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &secresult) != errSecSuccess) { // ERROR 2
   return;
}
```

ERROR 1 is:

```
'Int' is not convertible to 'SecTrustResultType'
```

ERROR 2 is:

```
 Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Now, I see that `SecTrustResultType` is a `UInt32` and `kSecTrustResultInvalid` is an `Int`... but this header is defined by Apple so I suppose that it should be correct :P

```
typealias SecTrustResultType = UInt32
var kSecTrustResultInvalid: Int { get }
```

About the second error I really don't know how to manage it since the function `SecTrustEvaluate` returns a `OSStatus` (that is an alias for `UInt32`) and `errSecSuccess` is a `OSStatus` too.

I'm really confused. Do you have any suggestion to make this stuff work!?

Comment: For your error 1, you can convert the Int to an UInt32: `var secresult: SecTrustResultType = UInt32(kSecTrustResultInvalid)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can init SecTrustResultType with this line in
**Swift 5**

```
var secResult = SecTrustResultType.invalid
```

Different from the other answers, I preferred a single result handle ( SecTrustResultType ) when I checked a server's Certificate Chain. Please see below:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        guard let trust: SecTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            return
        }

        var secResult = SecTrustResultType.invalid
        SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &secResult)
        switch secResult {
          case .proceed:
            // ✅
          case .recoverableTrustFailure:
            // ❌ check Root CA and Int CA trusted on IOS device
          default:
            // ❌ default error
        }

        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
```

Comment: 'SecTrustEvaluate' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: renamed to 'SecTrustEvaluateWithError(_:_:)'

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue myself and the header docs are a little bit confusing especially since the constants are defined as `Int`s and SecTrustResultType is defined as a `UInt32`.

But good news, the solution is rather simple just init `SecTrustResultType` with `kSecTrustResultInvalid`:

```
var secresult = SecTrustResultType(kSecTrustResultInvalid)
if (SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &secresult) != errSecSuccess){
       return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.3

```
var secresult = SecTrustResultType.Invalid
if (SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &secresult) != errSecSuccess){
       return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the great answer from [rustyMagnet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434127/4691224)

Updated for **Swift 5.4** and **macOS 11**

```swift
var secResult = SecTrustResultType.invalid
SecTrustGetTrustResult(trust, &secResult)
switch secResult {
case .proceed:
    // ✅
case .recoverableTrustFailure:
    // ❌ check Root CA and Int CA trusted on IOS device
default:
    // ❌ default error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Still remains same in Swift 3.0:

```
var secresult = SecTrustResultType.Invalid
if (SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &secresult) != errSecSuccess){
   return;
}
```